# How to get value of radio button in Controller

Tags: php, laravel

Good afternoon!

I have the following code in the jquery who it works correctly.

```
function countInputs(){
    var numElem = $('.name').size();
    $('.addTo').append('')                    
    .append('<input type="radio" name="location'+numElem+'" value="0">Yes')
    .append('<p>')
    .append('<input type="radio" name="location'+numElem+'" value="1">No estoy en el punto de interés')  
}
```

I receive an array of radio buttons name location1 , location2 , location3 but I /don't know how to read the value of this elements in the Controller , could anyone help to me ?

```
  public function store(StoreDiarioRequest $request){

    $nombre = \Request::input("name");
    $descripcion = \Request::input("description");
    $fechaSalida = \Request::input("startDate");
    $fechaLlegada = \Request::input("finalDate");
    $informacion = \Request::input("information");    
    $pi = \Request::input('puntoInt');

    var_dump($request->input('location'))


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use input as array `[]` in html inputs, replace your javascript with this :

**Javascript**

```
function countInputs(){
    var numElem = $('.name').size();
    $('.addTo').append('')                    
    .append('<input type="radio" name="location[]" value="0">Yes')
    .append('<p>')
    .append('<input type="radio" name="location[]" value="1">No estoy en el punto de interés')  
}
```

and access it like this in your php :

**PHP**

```
<?php var_dump($request->input('location')) ?> // should output an array of your radio location Array(true, false, true, true ...);
```

Comment: You mean var_dump($request->input('location')) output you null ?

Comment: Can you put your PHP code in your question pls ? :)